# SharePoint 2007 Approval Workflow - Any other person can approve requirement

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I use SharePoint's Content Approval to enforce the rule that any two people in a group can make a change?

We have a policy library that any two individuals can update (a modifier and an approver). If I do a group parallel approval, the modifier can approve their own work (I believe).

Unfortunately, I don't have access to Visual Studio or even SharePoint Designer (as these have been disabled by corporate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straight forward

Add two users to approver group, Assign the workflow task to the Approvers group. Any one from the group can approve the workflow to initiate its next phase